# Add filter in function inside EntityCrudController (Easyadmin 3.5.7 with Symfony 4.4.51)

Tags: symfony, filter, easyadmin, symfony-4.4, easyadmin3

I'd like to check if filters are applied inside an `Action` function configured with `configureActions()` and, if not, I want to apply a filter (I have already filters classes programmed (with `implements FilterInterface`, all ok there).

But I cannot see a way to programmatically apply the filter...

I can obtain all filters with:

```
$filters = $this->get(FilterFactory::class)->create($context->getCrud()->getFiltersConfig(), $fields, $context->getEntity());
```

but I don't know what to do with it, and there's no `->applyFilter()` that I can use on any object. Also I don't want to change the URL to apply the filter there because filters are complex queries already programmed in `Admin/Filter` and that seems like doing tricks to something that should be more direct, but I can't find the way even then.